# Implementation of Vector3.RotateTowards from Unity

Tags: unity, rotation, vector

I'm using vector3 as direction of object movement and i want to smoothly rotate it to another direction vector. I found [SLERP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67919193/how-does-unity-implements-vector3-slerp-exactly) but it rotate by percent. Looks like [Vector3.RotateTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.RotateTowards.html) is what i need, but i can't find the source code of this method and my project is **not** on Unity.

So, can you help me realize rotation like SLERP but by **fixed angle**? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example implementation:

```
Vector3 fromDirection = fromVector.normalized;
Vector3 toDirection = toVector.normalized;

float angleRadians = Mathf.Acos(Vector3.Dot(fromDirection, toDirection));

float angleDegrees = Mathf.Min(angleRadians * Mathf.Rad2Deg, maxAngleDegrees);

Vector3 axis = Vector3.Cross(fromDirection, toDirection);

Quaternion rotationIncrement = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angleDegrees, axis);

outputVector = rotationIncrement * fromVector;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, is there a way to do this without a quaternion?

Comment: Sure. [Use the angle and axis to construct a rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Axis_and_angle) instead.